# How to get host component instance in directive without knowing its type in Angular8+?

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-directive, angular-translate, angular-i18n

I am creating a custom "i18n" directive to update textual value in attributes of host component. So I came across a scenario that is, when the host component is a custom component then I also need to update property of component which is taking input from the attribute using @Input(). So looking for a way to get component instance (which can be a custom component as well as could be simply a DIV or SPAN).

I came across a way around as follows:

```
this._viewContainerRef['_lContainer'][0] // To access instance of host, if it is a HTMLElement

this._viewContainerRef['_lContainer'][0][8]; // To access instance of host, if it is a custom component
```

But both the approaches fail my test cases, since _viewContainerRef is a little different when running tests with Jest (i.e. tests running in a headless browser).

Hence looking for some suggestions or inputs.